# How to fix the problem jquery and angular etc. not found?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, frontend, bower

I'm fairly new with using frontend tools like grunt, bower etc. At the moment I'm working on a project that uses angular for the frontend and JavaEE for the backend. The war file is generated using maven. I'm using the exec-maven-plugin to call node.js, bower and grunt. When I execute maven to build the artifact, everything works fine and it generates a war file. The problem is that the frontend doesn't work in the browser. When I use grunt to generate all those frontend no error/warning will occure/happen. Also the verbose switch of grunt build does not offer any errors/warnings. At the end the browser 'says' that jquery, angular etc. is not found.

[Broser error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLHeu.png)

```
// Gruntfile.js

'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
        useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
        ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
        cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
    });

    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        dist: '../target/generated-sources'
    };

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-constant');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-install-simple");

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: appConfig,
        ngconstant: {
            options: {
                space: ' ',
                wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}',
                name: 'the_app.config',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/enviroment/config.js'
            },
            development: {
                constants: {
                    ENV: {
                        name: 'development',
                        appName: 'the_app',
                        hostEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/the_app/'
                    }
                }
            },
            deployment: {
                constants: {
                    ENV: {
                        name: 'deployment',
                        appName: 'the_app'
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        "bower-install-simple": {
            options: {
                directory: 'lib',
                color: true,
                interactive: false
            },
            "dev": {
                options: {
                    production: false
                }
            },
            "prod": {
                options: {
                    production: true
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer:server']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
                tasks: ['ngconstant:development']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use('/lib', connect.static('./lib')),
                            connect().use('/app/styles', connect.static('./app/styles')),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use('/lib',connect.static('./lib')),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: {
                src: [
                    'Gruntfile.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                ]
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
                },
                src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    map: true,
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },
        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
            },
            test: {
                devDependencies: true,
                src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
                ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
                fileTypes:{
                    js: {
                        block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
                        detect: {
                            js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                        },
                        replace: {
                            js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}lib\//
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
                importPath: './lib',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images',
                httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/the_app/images',
                    httpFontsPath: '/the_app/fonts',
                    outputStyle: 'compressed',
                    debugInfo: false,
                    noLineComments: true
                }
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    sourcemap: true
                }
            }
        },
        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
                    ],
                    patterns: {
                        js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
                    }
            }
        },
        uglify:        {
            onlyScripts: {
                files:   [{
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js',
                    src:  ['.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js']
                }]
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: ['*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        ngtemplates: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    module: 'the_app',
                    htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
                    usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
                },
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: 'modules/**/*.html',
                dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
            }
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        '*.html',
                        'lib/font-awesome/css/*',
                        'lib/font-awesome/fonts/*',
                        'lib/pixeden-stroke-7-icon/pe-icon-7-stroke/fonts/*',
                        'fonts/**/*',
                        'images/**/*',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        'language/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    src: 'lib/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                },{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    src: 'lib/font-awesome/css/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'lib/font-awesome/',
                    src: 'fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'lib/pixeden-stroke-7-icon/pe-icon-7-stroke/',
                    src: 'fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'lib/flag-icon-css/',
                    src: 'flags/**/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            },
            images: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.*'
            },
            vendors: {
                expand: true,
                cwd:    '.tmp/concat/scripts/',
                dest:   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/',
                src:    ['vendor.js', 'modernizr.custom.js', 'vendor.codemirror.js'],
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'compass:server'
            ],
            test: [
                'compass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'compass:dist'
            ]
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'ngconstant:development',
            'wiredep',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer:server',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });
    grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
    });
    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'ngconstant:deployment',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
    ]);
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'ngconstant:deployment',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify:onlyScripts',
        'copy:vendors',
        'filerev',
        'copy:images',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "asDemo",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-cli-font-awesome": "^1.4.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-bower-install-simple": "~1.1.4",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.3",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-karma": "^3.0.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-upload-file": "0.0.2",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "karma": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

I would expect that the frontend has all required libraries present but the browser does not find jquery, angular etc.

Comment: Why don't you use the built in CLI/webpack builder of Angular instead of Grunt? Are you confusing Angular with AngularJS?

Comment: Because I am fairly new with all this frontend stuff. I don't know much about the alternatives and the existing project is like it is.

Comment: You first need to differ between Angular and Angular*JS*, which is essential to be able to answer your question. What does Angular packages does your `package.json` include?

Comment: We use AngularJS at this time. I added the package.json content above.

Comment: I changed your tag accordingly then to get the right peoples attention.